# RSA key fingerprints don't match

Tags: ssh, iphone, ios

I'm trying to ssh to my iPhone from my mac and I got the following message:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.253 (192.168.1.253)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:P8yscqMVDOPOQ24i3qJjcm4hUMeeuxDy7JkRegtV20Q.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

On my iPhone I typed `ssh-keygen -lf /var/mobile/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to check my fingerprint and the fingerprint displayed didn't match the fingerprint displayed on my mac.

Why wouldn't the fingerprints match and how can I fix it without compromising the connection, e.g to a man in the middle?

I have have really no clue what's going on, I've just been searching for a solution so I was hoping someone could help me

---

**Update**

I ran `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` instead, and this indeed matched. Am I on the clear to connect?

Answer (score 3):

> Why wouldn't the fingerprints match

Because there are two keypairs, and they have different (opposite) purposes.

- The keypair at `~/.ssh/id_rsa[.pub]` authenticates the *client* (you) to the server. It's used when you SSH from the Mac to other hosts (the iPhone in your case) and lets you log in to those hosts without a password.
- The keypair at `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key[.pub]` authenticates the *server* (iPhone) to your client. It's used when you SSH from other hosts to the iPhone and lets you verify that you're connecting to the correct device.

Comment: This drove me absolutely nuts for two days, because it's not the way I understood it from the tons of HowTos on the internet. Finally, this answer shed some light.